# AppVeyor can't restore fody.targets

Tags: continuous-integration, appveyor

I try to setup appveyor for my project on github. I added the "nuget restore" command to the pre build. But now I get this error message:

```
"C:\projects\moneyfox\Src\MoneyFox.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\projects\moneyfox\Src\MoneyFox.Windows\MoneyFox.Windows.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\projects\moneyfox\Src\MoneyFox.Shared\MoneyFox.Shared.csproj" (default target) (3) ->
(EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports target) -> 
  C:\projects\moneyfox\Src\MoneyFox.Shared\MoneyFox.Shared.csproj(276,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\Fody.1.29.4\build\portable-net+sl+win+wpa+wp\Fody.targets.
"C:\projects\moneyfox\Src\MoneyFox
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by first let appveyor select the build configuration by his own and second by execute nuget restore directly on the sln file:

```
nuget restore Src\MoneyFox.sln
```